# C# xmlserialization SoapEnvelope namespace formating

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, soap

Im having issues building a soapenvelope in c#. Here is an example of desired field in output

```
<xml version="1.0">
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="id1">
<Body d2p1:type="Body" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<test xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d2p1:type="q1:string">hello
</test>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

However when I serialize the class i get this

```
<xml version="1.0">
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="id1">
<test href="#id2" />
</Envelope>
<Body id="id2" d2p1:type="Body" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<test xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d2p1:type="q1:string">hello
</test>
</Body>
```

As you can see the body is outside the envelope.

Here is the class
    namespace soaptest
    {

```
public class Envelope
{
    public Body test;
}


public class Body
{
    public string test;
}

}
```

And here is how Im serializing

```
Envelope test = new Envelope();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

test.test = new soaptest.Body();
test.test.test = "hello";

XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

SoapReflectionImporter importer = new SoapReflectionImporter();
XmlTypeMapping map = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Envelope));
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(map);
writer.WriteStartElement("xml version=\"1.0\"");
serializer.Serialize(writer, test);

ms.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
string output = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Now I can do away with all attributes atm.  I just need it to be

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Envelope>
 <Body>
 //body elements
 </Body>
 </Envelope>
```

So how can I get the serializer to do this?  Or is there a good SoapEnvelope Library for .net?

Answer (score 1):

Why so complex?

Model:

```
public class Envelope
{
    public Body Body;
}
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement("test")]
    public string Test;
}
```

Usage:

```
Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
envelope.Body = new Body();
envelope.Body.Test = "hello";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, envelope);
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="cp866"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Body>
    <test>hello</test>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```